# Auto Complete Behaving strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

i am using Jquery AutoComplete and after i made first selection and then leave the textbox and then if i come again to the same first textbox its automatically calling onSelecting

```
 $('#autocomplete-ajax1').autocomplete({

        lookup: countriesArray,
        lookupFilter: function (suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
            var re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
            return re.test(suggestion.value);
        },
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            debugger;
            //$('#autocomplete-ajax1').val($('#autocomplete-ajax1').val().trim());
            AutoFill(suggestion.value);
            $('#selction-ajax1').val(suggestion.data);
        }

    });
```

Jquery.js: 1.9.1
jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js : 1.9.2

Comment: create a demo that replicates the problem

Comment: Hey i have sorted out the issue. The issue is with triggerSelectOnValidInput in the options of the autocomplete it is firing onSelect as soon as there is a match found with the textbox value

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with triggerSelectOnValidInput in the options of the autocomplete it is firing onSelect as soon as there is a match found with the textbox value

```
$('#autocomplete-ajax1').autocomplete({

        triggerSelectOnValidInput :false,
        lookup: countriesArray,
        lookupFilter: function (suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
            var re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
            return re.test(suggestion.value);
        },
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            debugger;
            //$('#autocomplete-ajax1').val($('#autocomplete-ajax1').val().trim());
            AutoFill(suggestion.value);
            $('#selction-ajax1').val(suggestion.data);
        }

    });
```